# Recursive function to traverse object

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to traverse the following object and return all jobs including sub jobs as a linear array:

```
var o = {
    id: 1,
    subJobs: {
        a: {
            id: 2,
            subJobs: {}
        },
        c: {
            id: 3,
            subJobs: {
                b: {
                    id: 4,
                    subJobs: {}
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Here is the function that I wrote:

```
function parseSubJobs(job) {
    var jobs = [];
    if (Object.keys(job.subJobs).length > 0) {
        for (var key in job.subJobs) {
            var j = parseSubJobs(job.subJobs[key]);
            Array.prototype.push.apply(jobs,j);
        }
        jobs.push(job);
        return jobs;
    }

    return [job];
}

var parsed = parseSubJobs(o);
```

It works OK, but it seems to me that the solution can be improved. I'm not very good with recursions, so can it be improved?

Comment: If you have working code, and you're just looking for optimization help, you are best suited heading over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. We help fix broken code here, not (potentially) bad code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can.

1. Iinitialize `jobs` with `job`
2. Skip `if (Object.keys(job.subJobs).length > 0) {` (see point 4.)
3. Iterate over the keys
4. Change the function to a function with only one exit.

```js
var o = { id: 1, subJobs: { a: { id: 2, subJobs: {} }, c: { id: 3, subJobs: { b: { id: 4, subJobs: {} } } } } };

function parseSubJobs(job) {
    var jobs = [job];
    Object.keys(job.subJobs).forEach(function (key) {
        jobs = jobs.concat(parseSubJobs(job.subJobs[key]));
    });
    return jobs;
}

var parsed = parseSubJobs(o);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(parsed, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```